# Ruby on Rails - SMTP authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, mailer

Hey guys I want to send an email when an user registers. so i have these settings:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "GMAIL_USERNAME",
    password: "GMAIL_PASSWORD"
  }
```

I have set the username and password variables and tried to have them like `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` and how you see in the code above and I always get the same error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in UsersController#create 
534-5.7.14   *and some link*
```

Are my settings wrong? I've even tried that google display unlock thing. But it still can't login

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir

Comment: Please change your host as well for production it should not `localhost:300`