# Actionmailer cannot send using Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

With the same config/application.rb (see below), I can send with one Gmail account, but not for a second Gmail account.  The second Gmail account is preferred, I verified the login credentials with a browser and have ensured it accepts "less secure apps".

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
user_name:            'accountname',
password:             'secret',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true
```

Also with the second Gmail, I got NET::SMTPAUthenticationError in production, and it just does not send in development mode without complaining.

Finally, I am using Rails console, and my objective is to use a rake task to send email instead of in the web environment.

Comment: You said "Without complaining". Show us how it complains, please.

Comment: Only in production I got: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs1B

 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:960:in `check_auth_response'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:737:in `auth_plain'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:729:in `authenticate'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:564:in `do_start'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
 from /home/hpmini/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
...

Comment: Are you sending mail to some android, ios specific? If that is the case, then you need add two factor passwords. Google has added these features.

Comment: I tried sending to one Yahoo and one Hotmail account.  Both of them work for one account and not the other.

Comment: You mentioned you ensured under Google account settings that it accepts 'less secure apps'.  Good now try this.  Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue (this will grant access for 10 minutes for registering new apps). After this my app in production started sending emails ;) [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir/20262500#20262500)