# How configure my server to send emails from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using the server that comes with Rails and I need to configure it to send emails to recipients such as juan@gmail.com and pepe@hotmail.com.

Do I need to use my Gmail account or install a local SMTP service. I'm a newbie in ruby on rails

I am executing this using Mailers.

An example that I saw on internet is below.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send mail from local put the code below in you config/application.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => 'your_email_id',
      :password             => 'password',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Add the below line in application.rb file...

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost', :port => 3000 }
```

Comment: I just got gmail smtp working with similar settings above. Depending on your gmail account, you may have to grant 'device' access in order to use gmail smtp.  [See here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir/20262500#20262500). I had to grant device access to my development and production machines, plus under google Account Settings > Allow access for 'less secure' apps.

Answer (score 0):

To send mail from local put the code below in you config/environments/devleopment.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<your gmail username>',
  password:             '<and its password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

REF :http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html