# RoR: Issues with sending mails using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have set up a new rails project with user registration through devise gem. However, I am facing issues in the user registration. I tried using both sendgrid and gmail settings using the setup_mail.rb file below.

I have browsed through all the stackoverflow questions related to emails not working with devise but to no avail.

The errors I get are

1.) When using the sendgrid settings

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
535 Authentication failed: account disabled
```

[image]

2.) When using the gmail settings. I have enabled the less secure apps in google for my account.

The relevant files are

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtq-
```

> config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method =  :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =  {
  :address                  =>  'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port                     =>  587,
  :authentication           =>  :plain,
  :user_name                =>  'appname@heroku.com',
  :password                 =>  'password',
  :domain                   =>  'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto     =>  true
}


# ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =  {
#   :address                  =>  'smtp.gmail.com',
#   :port                     =>  587,
#   :authentication           =>  :plain,
#   :user_name                =>  'user@gmail.com',
#   :password                 =>  'password',
#   :domain                   =>  'gmail.com',
#   :enable_starttls_auto     =>  true
# }
```

> config/environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true


  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options =  {:host => 'localhost:3000'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
end
```

Output from the development log

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 8.3ms

Sent mail to w@ew.com (2360.5ms)
Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 14:59:36 +0530
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: w@ew.com
Message-ID: <5616378020219_5ae128535fc52153@Battosai.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome w@ew.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=3WrsLhb_hkNgxeGx-HhC">Confirm my account</a></p>

  [1m[36m (0.7ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2491ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu-7
):
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:976:in `check_auth_response'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:740:in `auth_plain'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:732:in `authenticate'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:567:in `do_start'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
  actionmailer (4.2.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionmailer (4.2.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:541:in `deliver_mail'
  mail (2.6.3) lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `deliver'
  actionmailer (4.2.4) lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
  devise (3.5.2) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:170:in `send_devise_notification'
  devise (3.5.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:116:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
  devise (3.5.2) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:172:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_create_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
  devise (3.5.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/ankit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (12.8ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.7ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (37.7ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (19.0ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (38.7ms)
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir - tldr; try clearing the gmail captcha from the IP of your machine, and/or change the password to refresh the security

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have even tried sendgrid. Furthermore, this is not working even in the development mode once I set config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

Comment: The sendgrid error is easily google-able ("sendgrid rails 535 error"), it leads you to this perhaps? did sendgrid ever work at all or is it a new account? https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181628 - your code looks fine, it's just both mail providers need something from you.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on "access to less secure app" for gmail from which you are sending mail.
https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps.