# Heroku Action Mailer with Gmail, sends email only once = Net::SMTPAuthenticationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

Strange behaviour I have. I'm using gmail to send my emails in my Rails app. I have my gmail configured to accept less secure apps.
However I send one email and then when I go to my google account it prompts me to restore the account via my phone.

After that, my app no longer sends email and I get this in my Heroku logs:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again.
```

My `production.rb` is set up this way:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => 'xxx@gmail.com',
   :password             => 'xxxxxx',
   :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  }
```

Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the `domain` to `gmail.com`

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "gmail.com",
      :user_name            => "xxx@gmail.com",
      :password             => "xxxxxxx",
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

If it worked then ok, if not try to change the `:authentication` to `:login`.

*Advice:* Check Gmail's security events too and double-check that all security settings are intact.

Answer (score 0):

So I had several problems. The one that was caused by my inattention was that I didn't read Figaro gem docs properly and I wasn't sending out the proper info to Heroku with `figaro heroku:set -e production`.

Secondly my account would go into lockdown after I created it and sent first email. Steps to do:

- enable two-step verifiation
- generate app specific keys
- put them in your `config/application.yml` if you're using Figaro
- push and run figaro command
- you might have to clear CAPTCHA on gmail see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the coment by @Mohamed
Advice: Check Gmail's security events too and double-check that all security settings are intact.
LINK: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps