# Rails, Heroku and contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to implement a simple contact form inside my app. Read through couple of SO posts but still no full solution.

My contact form is working in the development environment. 
Here is my setup in the config file:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'my_app_name.herokuapp.com' }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :domain         => 'mail.google.com',
    :port           => 587,
    :user_name      => 'my_email@gmail.com',
    :password       => 'my_password',
    :authentication => :plain,
  }
```

What I get after running `heroku logs` is:

```
2016-10-14T21:08:48.912404+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-10-14T21:08:48.912360 #3]  INFO -- : [eb99e511-dde1-45bc-b56a-6a919f519800] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 858ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2016-10-14T21:08:48.912986+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-14T21:08:48.912936 #3] FATAL -- : [eb99e511-dde1-45bc-b56a-6a919f519800]   
2016-10-14T21:08:48.913019+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-10-14T21:08:48.912985 #3] FATAL -- : [eb99e511-dde1-45bc-b56a-6a919f519800] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuE
```

I have also read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir), turned on the things that the answer and the comment advised to, but the error still appears.

Anything I missed?

Are there any gems/ plugins that I should consider using instead of built-in ActionMailer?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Sendgrid free plan. Good documentation so it was simple to implement.