# smtp settings in rails working locally but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am building a contact form in Rails. I am using gmail to send messages. It works perfectly in development, but not in production. Heroku gives me this error:

```
2017-02-03T21:47:02.629544+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-03T21:47:02.629450 #4]  INFO -- : [082aab82-7b98-45b4-97da-b92470134ef8] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 731ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-03T21:47:02.630122+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-03T21:47:02.630063 #4] FATAL -- : [082aab82-7b98-45b4-97da-b92470134ef8]   
2017-02-03T21:47:02.630180+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-03T21:47:02.630122 #4] FATAL -- : [082aab82-7b98-45b4-97da-b92470134ef8] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsT
```

Which seems to indicate it is having trouble with my smtp settings. Here ae my settings in my production environment. Can anyone help?

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => "587",
:domain => "gmail.com",
:user_name => "myeamil@gmail.com",
:password => "mypassword",
:authentication => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Net::SMTPAuthenticationError when sending email from Rails app (on staging environment)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'SENDGRID' addon on heroku.

Just add sendgrid addon from resources tab in your heroku app and settings in your production.rb file will be as below:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings= { 
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'gmail.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```