# Action Mailer Returning SMTPAuthentcationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am running into the error displayed in the link every time i try to send email via rails 'localhost' or 'c9'. I have enabled "less secure apps" on google account and tried all the guidelines but the error is still the same. Seeking help folks.
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQyOI.png)

The source files are as below:
suggestion_mailer.rb

```
  class SuggestionMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.suggestion_mailer.new_suggestion.subject
  #
  def new_suggestion()
   #@suggestion = suggestion


  mail( :from => "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
        :to => "yyyyyyyyyyyyyygmail.com",
        :subject => 'Thanks for signing up for our amazing app'
  )
 end
end
```

suggestion_controller.rb

```
def create
 @suggestion = Suggestion.new(suggestion_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @suggestion.save
    SuggestionMailer.new_suggestion().deliver
    format.html { redirect_to suggestions_url, notice: 'Suggestion was 
    successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: 
  @suggestion }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @suggestion.errors, status: 
   :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

development.rb

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :domain               => "mail.google.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
   :password             => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
   :authentication       => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
   #:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
}

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', 
      port: 3000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The config seems correct. Can you try removing the domain? If you wish to use the domain, use `'gmail.com'` instead of `mail.google.com`. The following is my config. Note that i have used `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {` and not `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {`. I'm not sure if this would be an issue.

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true  

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'username@gmail.com'}

  # Mail settings
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => 'username@gmail.com',
   :password             => 'password',
   :authentication       => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

**Edit**

As Justin said, you have to enable the nable less secure apps in google. The same can be from [here](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/security) at the bottom. Something like in the image below

[image]

I faced another issue while sending the mails from the production environment. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir) helped me figure out another thing i need to take care of for same. Apparently you need to provide access to apps. You can do it from [here](http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha). Just have to click the continue and wait for 10 mins for the changes to take place.

You're good to go after this for sending out emails from production.

***Side Note:** I faced the above issue when i deployed the app in Heroku *

Comment: Hey, just tried your suggestion but still no success. I think the problem is google acc settings(correct me if am wrong), I just don't know how to go about it. Thanks though.

Comment: We don't have to make any google settings as far as i'm aware. Are you sure you're using the correct credentials. Maybe try replacing the username and password directly without the environment variables. In case thats the issue?

Comment: You have to enable less secure apps in google. I already tried using the raw credentials other than environment variables but still didn't work.