# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError Rails Mailer Doesn't work with new email address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail

It worked for my other Gmail account 5 minutes ago so I know my config is all correct but now I'm getting an authentication error. I just made a new Gmail account and changed the username and password in my `development.rb` file and now it doesn't work.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "locahost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :enable_starttls_auto => true,
   :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
   :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
   :domain               => 'localhost',
   :authentication       => :plain
}
```

This thread helped me last time but like I said I don't know what else to try..? [Net::SMTPAuthenticationError when sending email from Rails app (on staging environment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124878/netsmtpauthenticationerror-when-sending-email-from-rails-app-on-staging-envir)

For my new Gmail account two-factor authentication is OFF, I turned ON the setting to allow less secure apps as I had to for my other account. AND I also went here https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and allowed account access. Not sure what I missed...Probably something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

If two-factor authentication is ON go to the [app passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) section, then in the first select choose "Other (custom name)", enter the name of your application and click "generate". After that you get a pop-up with the password you have to use in your action mailer settings.

*if two-factor authentication is OFF, enable it first.

Comment: This worked for me!  Thanks