# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError ruby on heroku with gmail works but fails again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmail

I have problems sending mail from a ruby production app on heroku by a gmail smtp account.

[Here i found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262500/4027355)

When i apply the solution all works wel, but after a while the problems comes back.

Do i have to set something in my google account to make it permanent ?

I think it has to do with the fact that i am using a free heroku account.
The servers stops after a while an perhaps has to login in gmail when it starts up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to make it permanent because Gmail doesn't want its service to be used to send out automated e-mails(*).

There are some providers that will make it much easier for you:

- https://sendgrid.com/pricing/ has a free plan (up to 100 emails/day)
- https://postmarkapp.com/pricing gives you 10k emails for 10$)

or take your pick, because the market seem to be pretty saturated: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=e-mail+delivery+service&ia=web

(*) What I suspect they do (though I could not find info about it) is that they can see if "same e-mails" are sent within short intervals.

You might try your luck (if it makes sens, when for example it's a toy project) to alter each e-mail contents to make it seem like different e-mail each time. But it will be just easier to go with free option in any other providers that **actually want** you to use it in your app.

Comment: Grzegorz, thanks for your reponse. I am not clear though, is it the combination gmail heroku that makes this problem? Gmail smtp should work in a normal production enviroment with ror alot of people are using this i think ?  (i do not think it has anything to do with the content. The e-mail works one or two emails are send, after some time e-mail is blocked again)

Comment: Possibly Gmail knows that Heroku IPs (or maybe even AWS's IPs) are a typical source of e-mail spam and treats it especially harshly? It's pure speculation. Please explain why you prefer Gmail for sending the mails, maybe there's better approach to fill that (hidden) requirement without Gmail?

Comment: So i think i got gmail working not fully tested jet, but after an update the mail worked again.  So in order to make gmail work i had to make 2 step verification work on the google account. After this i got the option to add an app password. I generated an app password put it in the config/initializers/setup_email.rb and rebuild the site.  I hope this solved my problem, but have to wait a day before i know for sure.

Comment: Everything is still working so the problem is solved. I red somewhere just changing the password solved the problems from some people. So i do not know if 2 step verification was needed and just changing the password would have solved the problem. Thanks for your input Grzegorz.

Comment: No problem :) Happy coding!