# Action Mailer, production mode, heroku and gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

Action Mailer works for my app in development mode but not in production mode. I have pulled together a few possible solutions, none of which work for me.

production.rb:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect" # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Include generic and useful information about system operation, but avoid logging too much
  # information to avoid inadvertent exposure of personally identifiable information (PII).
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Don't log any deprecations.
  config.active_support.report_deprecations = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require "syslog/logger"
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new "app-name")

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV['gmail_username'],
    password:             ENV['gmail_password'],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    open_timeout:         5,
    read_timeout:         5}


  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'xxxxx@gmail.com'}
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'MY-APP.herokuapp.com' }

end
```

I have tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997192/how-to-set-up-mailer-in-rails-app-for-production-environment-on-heroku). I unlocked CAPTCHA on gmail by following this link: http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha. I have 2FA activated on my gmail account but am using an app-specific password.

How do I get Action Mailer to work in production on Heroku?

Comment: check your logs if there is some errors

Comment: I don't know what that means. Which logs?

Comment: heroku logs --tail
Try to send email and see if you have any errors

Comment: Thanks for your input. I got it to work by fooling around with the recommended production settings in my app. The info I found on how to get this working on Heroku was very varied, I just had to do a combination of suggestions until it worked..

Comment: Hi Michael, could you, please, elaborate on this "fooling around"? Could you, share some details?

Comment: I don't remember exactly. It just took lots of tinkering to get it to work. Do you have a specific question?